# How to express the range $y=(-\infty,-1)\cup(0,\infty)$ with set builder notation?

Tags: notation

I am trying to express the range and domain of a function with set builder notation. The domain is easy to express because it's just $\{x:x\in\mathbb{R}\backslash\{-1\}\}$, but the range is $y=(-\infty,-1)\cup(0,\infty)$ and I'm not sure how to express that $y$ is all real numbers outside of $[-1,0]$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use inequalities or the "different" sign. For instance the domain could be $\{x\in \mathbb R : x\neq 1\}$.